# Retrieving and locating cell value in Excel

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

Hopefully i will explain clear enough, I have a List of objects ( each object have 3 properties ) those objects are printed to xls file, I am trying to locate the cell where the value were assigned first and the last in order to get a references and setFormula to get Sum of all of the middle values

[image]

```
 public String getCellReference(int rowPosition, int cellPosition) {
    CellReference reference = new CellReference(rowPosition, cellPosition);
    return reference.formatAsString();
}

  public String getCellReference(int rowPosition, int cellPosition) {
    CellReference reference = new CellReference(rowPosition, cellPosition);
    return reference.formatAsString();
}

public String getSumFormula(int rowPosition, int cellPosition, int rowPosition2, int cellPosition2) {
    String startCell = getCellReference(rowPosition, cellPosition);
    String finishCell = getCellReference(rowPosition2, cellPosition2);
    return "SUM(" + startCell + ":" + finishCell + ")";
}
```

To locate first value and last its not a problem but its seems to be a problem for me to locate a cell indexes

```
public Cell locateCell(List<Invoice> invoices){
    BigDecimal firstGeneralTotal = invoices.get(0).generalTotal();
    BigDecimal lastGeneralTotal = invoices.get(invoices.size()-1).generalTotal();

}
```

Comment: How are you accessing the workbook? Do you use apache poi or any other library?

Comment: @deHaar Apache Poi Thank you

Comment: Is it always a sum over all cells in that column? I mean would it be enough to find the index of the last cell / the largest index?

Comment: @deHaar in order to calculate the SUM by the formula i need to locate cell index with a first assigned value and the last assigned value

Comment: I think you have to track the first cell yourself in the code (if it isn't always the same), isn't it you (or your code) inserting the values? If you are appending values to a row, then you can possibly use `Sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows()` (the amount of rows) or `Sheet.getLastRowNum()` (the largest index a row has) in order to get the last cell in a column.

Comment: Your last edit really confuses me... Where in that last method are you accessing an object of apache poi? I don't see any, but a `List<Invoice>` instead. Oh... are you trying to use the index of an `Invoice` in that list in order to find the (row-) index of a `Cell`?

Comment: @deHaar i was just  showing an example me getting the first and last values for a better explanation what i really want to achieve, you right though I can get total rows and access first row second cell and same with the last row

Comment: OK, got it... Then please add some error message or describe exactly what's wrong (wrong index? too large or too low? Is the problem in `new CellReference(rowPosition, cellPosition);` or anywhere else?

Comment: I posted my approach bellow , let me know what you think about it or if i have extra code there , it looks like i could minimize it , however its a methods which means that it will be shared between different types of excel

Answer (score 2):

Basic access using POI would be like this:

```
XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook( … );
XSSFSheet sheet = workbook1.getSheetAt(0);
XSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(0);
XSSFCell cell = row.getCell(0);

String value = cell.getStringCellValue();
```

Instead of using getStringCellValue you can also use one of those methods:

```
cell.getCellFormula()
cell.getNumericCellValue()
cell.getBooleanCellValue()
cell.getErrorCellValue()
```

Accordingly, you can do cell.setCellFormula(String formula) to set a cell.

If you want to add a formular to the end of the table containing the sum, you could use the cell references if you like. In this case, you'd need to [find the last row in the excel sheet](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFSheet.html#getPhysicalNumberOfRows%28%29):

```
sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows()
```

Then you could add a new row to the end of your sheet:

```
sheet.createRow(sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows()+1);
```

and put your sum in according cell.

Btw, I am not sure if I would use CellReferences, since they can contain references to other sheets as well. If I work only with a single sheet, I'd try to use the index numbers and translate them accordingly to A1:A200 etc.

Does this help you? If I got your question wrong, let me know in the comments, I may update my answer if possible.

Comment: Hey man, your post cleared my head a little , it did not answer my question but it definitely helped so thank you so much for the effort. I will post what i did so hopefully it will work

Comment: let me now what you think

Comment: I added something to my answer since I think I start to understand your use case :)

Answer (score 0):

```
 public String getCellReference(int rowPosition, int cellPosition) {
    CellReference reference = new CellReference(rowPosition, cellPosition);
    return reference.formatAsString();
}

public String getCoefficientFormula(int startRow, int firstCell, int endRow, int lastCell) {
    String firstReference = getCellReference(startRow, firstCell);
    String lastReference = getCellReference(endRow, lastCell);
    return firstReference + "/" + lastReference;
}

public String getSumFormula(int startRow, int endRow, int start, int finish) {
    String startCell = getCellReference(startRow,start);
    String finishCell = getCellReference(endRow,finish);
    return "SUM(" + startCell + ":" + finishCell + ")";
}
```